# NodeJS - Parse JSON (only strings or numbers)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, validation

I have got a little dilema what to do (What should I do). I've got in my app several places where I am using AJAX to transfer a JSON data. So for example receiving a data from the registration form:

```
try {
   var data = JSON.parse(json);
}
catch(e) {
   // ...
}

var fields = {
   firstName: data.firstName || "",
   lastName: data.lastName || "",
   ...
};
```

Then I need to do something with these fields. Let's say:

```
if (fields.firstName) {
   // OK save it to the DB
}

if(fields.lastName.xxx()) { // xxx() is a method that belongs to JS String Object
   // Do something...
}
```

The problem is what if `fields.firstName` or `fields.lastName` is `{}` / `[]`? That may happen if somebody sent a modified JSON with a wrong data types, the whole app will then crash since the method `xxx` is missing.

Do I have to check the type of every field whether it is really a string, a number, an array... or is there some another maybe nicer way how to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser -> https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator, also https://github.com/RushPL/node-screener

Comment: Use a JSON Schema validator, as for crashing tolerance use promises or try catch spaghetti

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that's a problem you'll have to face anytime using a dynamic language like JavaScript.

One possible solution is *not using String methods*, but creating a function that will check it's arguments first:

```
// original, with string methods
if (text instanceof String && text.trim().length === 0) { ... }

// alternative, define function first
var isEmptyString = function(text) {
  if (!(text instanceof String)) throw new Error("Argument must be a String");
  return text.trim().length === 0;
}

// use it in your code
if (isEmptyString(text)) { ... }
```

That can lead to cleaner code.
Just be sure not to define those functions in a global scope, when you have to use them in a Browser. Within the node.js modules that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make a little validator. Like that:

```
var format = {
  foo: "string",
  bar: "string"
};
var data = {
  foo: "bar",
  bar: []
}
var validate = function (data, format) {
  for(var d in data) {
    if(typeof data[d] !== format[d]) 
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(validate(data, format));
```

You can also remove invalid data like this:

```
var format = {
  foo: "string",
  bar: "string"
};
var data = {
  foo: "bar",
  bar: []
}
var validate = function (data, format) {
  for(var d in data) {
    if(typeof data[d] !== format[d]) 
      delete data[d];
  }
  return data;
}
console.log(validate(data, format));
```

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem I just don't like whole this validation. I think I will do some custom JSON.parse that will delete/filtrate objects & arrays...

Comment: "I will do some custom JSON.parse". No, no, no. There are already thousands of module you can use. For example https://github.com/RushPL/node-screener will do exactly that: "delete/filtrate objects & arrays".

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Tharabas suggests, you could take advantage of the 2nd argument of `JSON.parse` for doing your sanity check:

```
JSON.parse(data, function(key, value) {
  return key === 'firstName' ? cleanup(value) : '';
});
```

See this page for further information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse